# How to get value from many2one type using php

Tags: php, arrays, odoo, xml-rpc, many-to-one

I want to get partner data which is have information `id`, `name`, and `salesperson_id` where the 'salesperson_id' is many2one type (contains id and name). Here's my code :

```
    <?php
    // Login information
    $url = 'localhost';
    $url_auth = $url . '/xmlrp/common';
    $url_exec = $url . '/xmlrpc/object';

    $db = 'testing';
    $username = 'odoo';
    $password = 'odoo';

    // Ripcord can be cloned from https://github.com/poef/ripcord
    require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');

    // Login
    $common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/common");
    //$common = ripcord::client($url_auth);
    $uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

    //print("<p>Your current user id is '${uid}'</p>");

    $models = ripcord::client($url_exec);

    $customer = $models->execute_kw(
        $db,
        $uid,
        $password,
        'res.partner',
        'search_read', 
        array( // Search domain
            array(
                array('is_company', '=', true), // Query condition
                array('customer', '=', true)) // Query condition
            ),
        array('fields'=> array('name', 'salesperson_id'))
    );

    print("<p><strong>Found customers:</strong><br/>");
    foreach ($customer as $customers){
        print("${customers[id]}
               ${customers[name]}
               {$customers[salesperson_id][0]}

               <br/>");
        }
    print("</p>");
?>
```

It will show :

```
Found customers:
1234 CHLOE 12
1235 DRY MART 13
1236 SEEYOU 14
1237 ED. COMP 15
```

SOLVED!!

Comment: Your `${customers[salesperson_id]}` is returning an array when it should be returning a single integer. What does `customers[salesperson_id]` look like? I'm guessing you can access the ID with `${customers[salesperson_id][1]}`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, When i change it to `${customers[salesperson_id][1]}`, the page getting error `"This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"`

Comment: There is no field named salesperson_id for model res_partner. But you can get it from sale_order as the field user_id which shuld be salesperson_id

Comment: Is there no debugging tool on PHP letting you see exactly how `$customers[salesperson_id]` look like ? And then know exactly what to print ?

Comment: @Burmesepythis, in my sale.order model there's salesperson_id with type many2field.

Comment: that should be your custom module, you can see user_id.
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Salesperson', index=True, track_visibility='onchange', default=lambda self: self.env.user)

Comment: @Majikat, here's my array if I print the `$customer`

array(3) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["salesperson_id"]=> bool(false) ["id"]=> int(1234) ["name"]=> string(7) "CHLOE" }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["salesperson_id"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> int(12) [1]=> string(8) "MICHELLE" } ["id"]=> int(1235) ["name"]=> string(8) "DRY MART" }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["salesperson_id"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> int(15) [1]=> string(4) "BRYN" } ["id"]=> int(1236) ["name"]=> string(16) "SEEYOU COSMETICS" }
}

Comment: @Burmesepythis, what is it for? check the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to print the ID or the name of the Salesperson. But the problem with your code throwing a 500 Server Error is an IndexError. When you do `$customers[salesperson_id][1]`, it will fail on the first one because the user does not have a salesperson. Thus `$customers[salesperson_id]` is not an array but a Boolean, and trying to access any Index of it will throw an error.

I'm not good with PHP, so I'm just going to point out the answer :

- `$customers[salesperson_id][0]` is the ID of the salesperson, `$customers[salesperson_id][1]` is its name.
- if the customer does not have a salesperson, `$customers[salesperson_id]` will have `false` as value.

So the solution :

- Check if `$customers[salesperson_id]` is not `false`
- print `$customers[salesperson_id][0]` or `$customers[salesperson_id][1]` if `$customers[salesperson_id]` is not `false`